# arcore get light source location

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

new to AR development, just trying to get a sense of the possibilities with ARCore. Anyone know if there's a way to get the 3D location of the brightest visible point in ARCore's API. Hours of googling revealed plenty about shaders that react to environmental light, so the light's location/direction must be retrievable from somewhere in the program. I could always just find the brightest point from the 2D texture from the camera, but since ARCore is already figuring out where everything is in space for you, it seems reasonable that it could tell you where in space the brightest (ie most unique/placeable) point is. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show some code you have tried and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check out the official HelloAR tutorial of Google ?
There is an environmental light in your scene,which is the light source in your scene.They've also written a light estimation shader which is used by your scene during the rendering. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample

Comment: Thanks Bora, I've read that yeah. The question was about identifying the position of the light in world space- the environmental light prefab is just a script that allows ambient light information from the environment to interact with ARCore shaders. I am not asking about how to use those tools to light a scene, but how to actually get the 3D position of the light source itself, which is not clear from the tutorials.